# Html valid form function with jquery problems

Tags: jquery, html, forms

i made this script to validate a form in html, the problem is that when the button is pressed it restarts all the jquery code and i don't know why.

jquery:

```
function validForm(){

    if($("#name").val() == ""){
        alert("Name field can't be empty.");
        $("#name").focus();
        return false;
    }

    if($("#email").val() == ""){
        alert("E-mail field can't be empty.");
        $("#email").focus();
        return false;
    }
    if($("#message").val() == ""){
        alert("message field can't be empty.");
        $("#message").focus();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
};

$("#botonenviar").click( function() {
    if(validForm()){
        $.post("enviar.php",$("#formdata").serialize(),function(res){
            $("#formulario").fadeOut("slow");  
            if(res == 1){
                $("#exito").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");      
            } else {
                $("#fracaso").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");    
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your form is submitting on it's own, regardless of the outcome of your code. Either remove the form tags, or prevent the submit.

Comment: Try adding `return false` at the end of `$("#botonenviar").click( function() {});`

Comment: If you're going to use the click event, you'd be better off removing the form tags so that pressing enter on an input won't submit it bypassing your click event. Or better yet, use the submit event instead.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function() {
  if(validForm()){
    $.post("enviar.php",$("#formdata").serialize(),function(res){
        $("#formulario").fadeOut("slow");  
        if(res == 1){
            $("#exito").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");      
        } else {
            $("#fracaso").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");    
        }
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```